Error Loading Local Assets (gltf) in ar_flutter_plugin
I am using the ar_flutter_plugin to work with Augmented Reality in my Flutter project. When attempting to load local GLTF assets, I encounter inconsistent behavior. Specifically, GLTF files that do not reference any textures in subfolders of the assets directory load correctly, while those that do reference textures fail to load and throw an error.
Additional Information:
ar_flutter_plugin version: ^0.7.3
Local GLTF Files Without Textures
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBFi1ysf.png)
Local GLTF Files With Textures
(https://i.sstatic.net/oJNf5apA.png)
Inside GLTF Files With Textures
(https://i.sstatic.net/8M13jnPT.png)
Error Logs
(https://i.sstatic.net/lG0GkD49.png)
Steps to Reproduce:

Add GLTF files to the assets folder in the Flutter project.
Attempt to load GLTF files that have textures referenced in subfolders of the assets directory.
Observe that files without texture references load successfully, while files with texture references fail to load.

Expected Behavior:
All local GLTF files should load correctly, regardless of whether they reference textures in subfolders or not.
Actual Behavior:

GLTF files without texture references load successfully.
GLTF files with texture references in subfolders fail to load and produce an error.

